# Семантика перемещения на уровне ассемблера

Tags: c++, ассемблер

**C++:**

```
 #include <utility>
    int main()
    {
        int a =10;
        int b = std::move(a);
    }
```

**ASM:**

```
std::remove_reference<int&>::type&& std::move<int&>(int&):
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], rdi
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
        pop     rbp
        ret
main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 16
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-8], 10
        lea     rax, [rbp-8]
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    std::remove_reference<int&>::type&& std::move<int&>(int&)
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rax]
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], eax
        mov     eax, 0
        leave
        ret
```

Как семантика перемещения работает на уровне ассемблера?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Семантика перемещения - концепция уровня языка, построенная вокруг типа rvalue-ссылки, категории xvalue и связанных с этим типом правил разрешения перегрузок ("overload resolution").

На уровне ассемблера нет никакой разницы между rvalue-ссылкой и lvalue-ссылкой. Все *фундаментальные* типы всегда безусловно *копируются*, независимо того, является ли правая часть rvalue-ссылкой или нет. Для *пользовательских* же типов все определяется тем, что вы сами напишете в соответствующих перегруженных функциях. Что вы напишете - то и получится в ассемблере.

Другими словами, нет никакой "семантики перемещения" на уровне ассемблера. На уровне ассемблера есть только копирование. А вам, пользователю языка, в рамках языковой "семантики перемещения" лишь дается возможность выбрать, что (и как) копировать, а что не копировать.

---

В приведенном вами коде вы видите лишь не устраненный оптимизатором вызов функции `std::move`, которая "ничего не делает", а просто приводит свой аргумент к типу rvalue-ссылки. В коде, сгенерированном "начистовую" все эти "ничего не делающие" вызовы должны быть устранены и код должен быть эквивалентен простому

```
int a = 10;
int b = a;
```

Например

```
void foo(int &a, int &b, int &c, int &d)
{
  a = std::move(b);
  c = d;
}
```

при компиляции `g++ -O3` дает

```
foo(int&, int&, int&, int&):
    // a = std::move(b);
    mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rsi]
    mov     DWORD PTR [rdi], eax
    // c = d;
    mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rcx]
    mov     DWORD PTR [rdx], eax
    //
    ret
```

https://godbolt.org/z/O2WAmU

Comment: Другими словами в С++ чем дальше, тем больше делаются шаги лишь запутывающие программистов.

Comment: @avp: В связи с этой темой я бы так не сказал. Огромное количество делаемых в С++ шагов - это лишь "синтаксический сахар" над тем, что мы и так делали уже давно. Причем довольно удобный "синтаксический сахар".

Comment: @avp а где запутывание? Перемещение давно просилось в язык, и вот оно пришло. :)